# Access the outer scope

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to access the outer scope in this contrived example?

```
class KotlinTest {

    @Test
    fun `scoping head scratcher`() {
        
        data class MyData(val name:String)
        
        val name = "Happy Wok"
        val data = MyData(name)
        
        with(data) { 
            assert(name == this@name) // <-- fails to compile 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/this-expressions.html#qualified-this

Comment: You probably mean `this.name` (not `this@name`) in the line that you cannot compile. Put in the dot and the code compiles!

Comment: @aSemy - It does compile although I was expecting that `name` and `this.name` would be the same thing on the line in question.   Interesting design choice that I'll have wrap my head around.

    @Test
    fun `scoping head scratcher`() {
        
        data class MyData(val name:String)
        
        val name = "name"
        val data = MyData("data name")
        
        with(data) { 
            assert(name == this.name) // <-- fails to compile 
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

This works thanks to people that responded in the comments.

```
class KotlinTest {

    @Test
    fun `scoping head scratcher`() {

        data class MyData(val name: String, val name2: String)

        val name = "fun-name"
        val data = MyData("data-name", "data-name2")

        with(data) {
            assert(name == "fun-name")
            assert(name2 == "data-name2")
            assert(this@with.name == "data-name")
            assert(this.name == "data-name")
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the `assert(name == "fun-name")` to be "data-name" as `name2` is similarly visible, so this isn't intuitive to me.